# Ratio can you answer? please help me

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

In a mathematics club,there were 8 girls for every 5 boys.When 19 boys and 4 girls were added,the ratio became 9 girls for every 7 boys .How many girls were there at the start.

Answer (score 2):

If there were $8a(a>0)$ girls at the start, there were $5a$ boys

So, we have $$\frac{8a+4}{5a+19}=\frac97$$